# Uploading to Google Cloud via an asp.net webpage

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, google-cloud-storage

I have a webpage through which my users, using a mobile phone, can take pictures and upload them (hopefully) to the Google Cloud (I've got a JSON file, a platform project and an associated storage bucket, as well as all the login details).

However, I'm pretty new to all this and need to know how I'd get the file (coming from a standard `<input file="" name="fileupload"/>` ) to the Google Cloud space, and also to retrieve the URI of the file. Given that it's an asp.net webpage, I have access to Javascript and C#.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple of suggestions for you. We have other customers that have solutions which are similar to this architecture and so your proposed solution is good.

Google Cloud Storage (GCS) has a feature called [Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#Signed-URLs). This allows you to generate a secure URL to an object in a GCS bucket. My colleague wrote the C# sample for this:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#signing-code-csharp

There's a method in here that you can reuse GetSigningURL.

Each time a user requests the web page, you should generate a Signed URL and use this as the destination URL for the file upload location in your HTML.

If your HTML is generated by ASP.NET (MVC, Web Forms, Web Page), then you can make the call to GetSigningURL when the page is generated server-side. If not, you should wrap the C# code in a Web API and then you could use, e.g. jQuery ($.ajax), to call it from your client.

You may run your ASP.NET code on Google Cloud Platform using either Windows on [Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows) or using [Custom Runtimes on Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/).

Full disclosure: I'm a Googler working in cloud as a Strategic Customer Engineer.

Comment: I did not understand from your answer how do you actually do this, suppose I have an action in the project that allows the user to upload media to a local server and I want to change it from a local server to Google Cloud Storage, how do I do that? Can you show us a valid example please?

Comment: https://medium.com/net-core/using-google-cloud-storage-in-asp-net-core-74f9c5ee55f5 In this example I saw how to do this in an ASP .NET Core environment but my project is ASP .NET MVC